# Why won't my form close until the close button is clicked twice

Tags: winforms

We have an MDI child form called `Notes` which opens another form in this manner:

```
private void OpenRecentlyBilled()
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<RecentlyBilled>().Count() == 1) return;    
            Action<string, Form> lookupAction = (anoncode, form) =>
            {                    
                Lookup(anoncode);                   
            };    
            var F = new RecentlyBilled(lookupAction);
            F.Show(this);
        }
```

In the `Notes` Closing event, we first check to see if that `RecentlyBilled` form is open, and if so, close it:

```
private void Notes_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {          
        e.Cancel = false;
         if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<RecentlyBilledCases>().Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (RecentlyBilled f in Application.OpenForms.OfType<RecentlyBilled>())
            {
                f.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The `RecentlyBilled` form closes but the `Notes` MDI child form remains open until its [X] button is clicked a second time.

Would that be because the `RecentlyBilled` form hasn't been disposed yet, and has a reference to the `Notes` form that opened it and passed an Action to it?

Comment: Generally, you can't modify a collection in a for-each.

Comment: My crystal ball says that you are using Windows 7 so can't see the exception that is raised by this code.  Look in the Output window for the first chance exception notification.  Append .ToList() to avoid.

Comment: They're right. This works `Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form3>().ToList().ForEach(f => f.Close());`; a regular foreach like yours reproduces your issue. `Application.OpenForms` is necessarily altered by closing a form.

Comment: Where can I get me one of those crystal balls?